Flask app.config not loading settings from.ini file
I am trying to load settings from a .ini file into my Flask app's app.config object. The .ini file contains the following settings:
[Config]
DEBUG=False
TESTING=False

[DevelopmentConfig]
DEVELOPMENT=True
DEBUG=True

I have a Python file that loads these settings and returns a ConfigObject item:
import configparser, os
from colorama import Fore, Style, init

init(autoreset=True)

def load_config(configType):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    
    base_config = config['Config']
    
    if configType == 'Development':
        print(Fore.YELLOW + 'Development Config Selected')
        selected_config = config['DevelopmentConfig']
    elif configType == 'Production':
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'Production Config Running')
        selected_config = config['ProductionConfig']
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + f'Invalid config type: {configType}, defaulting to Production')
        selected_config = config['ProductionConfig']
    
    configDict = {**base_config, **selected_config}
    
    # Convert string values to boolean values
    configDict = {key: value.lower() == 'true' if value.lower() in ['true', 'false'] else value for key, value in configDict.items()}
    
    class ConfigObject(dict):
        def __init__(self, configDict):
            for key, value in configDict.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

            super().__init__(**configDict)
            
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.get(key)
    
    print(ConfigObject(configDict))
    return ConfigObject(configDict)

This function returns the correct settings:
{'debug': True, 'testing': False}
However, when I try to load these settings into my Flask app's app.config object, it does not work as expected:
from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

from utilities import load_config

app = Flask(__name__)
config_type = os.environ.get('CONFIG_TYPE', 'Production')
app.config.from_object(load_config(config_type))

print(app.config)

The app.config object is not loaded with the correct settings, instead it displays the default Flask settings:
<Config {'DEBUG': False, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'SECRET_KEY': None, 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': None, 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093}>

Why is my app.config object not loading the correct settings from the .ini file?
